# How many backpropogation passes on each set of inputs are required?

Tags: neural-network, computer-science, backpropagation

In a neural network how many passes on each input should I carry out?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific limit on the number of passes you have to carry out. It is simply based on the value of the error: you try to minimize it and you stop when you cannot do it anymore.

Comment: so I feed each input and output set until the difference between output node and the actual value is minimal?
When I do this the network then outputs just the last valu , no matter what the inputs.
Thanks for your reply